# javascript object property logs undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined, logging

ok so i have a js object declared at the top of my js file and at the bottom i have a function that is creating a property and adding a value to it but when i go to console log the new property in a different function it returns undefined but if i log the whole object it shows the object and the new property with its value below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var allVars={};
contentJson();
bioPageClass();


//start bioPage code.
function bioPageClass(){
    console.log(allVars.nums)
    //allVars.bioContent=allVars.allContent.theComittee.bios;
    allVars.timeTxt=allVars.allContent.theComittee.timeline;
    mouseEx();
    bioInfo(0);
    $('#next').click(function(){
                var itsindex = inkDot($('.dot').index($('.filled'))+1);

            });

            $('#pre').click(function(){
                var itsindex2 = inkDot($('.dot').index($('.filled'))-1);

            });

            function inkDot(dots){

                $('.dot').removeClass('filled');
                var equalize = dots < 0 ? 0 : dots;

                if(equalize <= $('.dot').length -1){
                $('.dot:eq('+equalize+')').addClass('filled');
                console.log('1st if '+equalize);
                bioInfo(equalize);
                }else{
                    equalize=0;
                    console.log('the else '+equalize);
                    $('.dot:eq('+equalize+')').addClass('filled');
                    bioInfo(equalize);
                }
            }

            function mouseEx(){
                $(".TLBtn").mouseover(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('clkd')){
                        $(this).addClass("timeROver");
                    }
                }).mouseout(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('clkd')){
                        $(this).removeClass("timeROver");       
                    }
                });

                $(".TLBtn").click(function(){
                    $(".TLBtn").removeClass('clkd timeROver');
                    $(this).addClass('clkd timeROver');
                })
            }

            function timeLineInfo(){

            }

            function bioInfo(ix){
                $('.bioCon').fadeOut(100, function(){
                    $('#bioImage > img').attr('src',bioContent[ix].image);
                    $('#bioName').html(allVars.bioContent[ix].name);
                    $('#bioTitle').html(allVars.bioContent[ix].title);
                    $('#bioDisc').html(allVars.bioContent[ix].details);
                    $('.bioCon').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        }
    //end bio page code.


            //call content json.
            function contentJson(){
                $.getJSON("content.json", function(json){
                allVars.allContent = json;
                allVars.nums = 8000;


                });
            }
});
```

what i'm i doing wrong here???

Comment: If you replace `console.log` with `alert`, is the output correct?

Comment: Works for me in Chromium 18.0.997.0, may be a browser issue.

Comment: The code as given works fine.

Comment: Is that exactly the code? I see no top/bottom of the JS file going on here.  The way I understand your description you're trying to access an object created like above with inline JS... which won't work unless it's called AFTER the `.ready` command has fired (after the DOM is loaded)

Comment: ok so for some reason this example now works but when i scale it to a larger amount of code it fails:

Comment: im editing my first post with the scaled code

Comment: so in this updated example the function that is adding the new property is at the bottom "contentJson" and the function doing the log is "bioPageClass" in it the "console.log(allVars.nums)" returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these functions are being run asynchronously and `bioPageClass` gets called before `getJSON` is done. Change it so that `bioPageClass` gets called as a callback.

You could do this if you wanted:

At the top:

```
contentJson(bioPageClass);
```

In `contentJson`:

```
function contentJson(callback){
  $.getJSON("content.json", function(json){
    allVars.allContent = json;
    allVars.nums = 8000;
    callback();
  });
}
```

But it may just be easier (and better practice) to pass allVars around rather than keeping it global. Define it in `contentJson` and then pass it to `bioPageClass`. Without the fancier callback, you could just do:

```
function contentJson(){
  var allVars = {};
  $.getJSON("content.json", function(json){
    allVars.allContent = json;
    allVars.nums = 8000;
    bioPageClass(allVars);
  });
}
```

Comment: In almost all cases, ajax functions will be run asynchronously so they don't block the interface as they're waiting for results. This is one of the all-time great features of Javascript. However, it means you have to be wary of problems like yours. Sequential position  in code doesn't always mean sequential execution. Whenever you want to be sure something runs after an ajax call, be sure to put it in the callback.

Comment: ah gotcha. well would it be bad practice to have one function (lets call it initAll) hold all the main function calls (e.g. biopageclass,homepageclass etc...) then have initAll as a callback(which would pass it the object allvars then it would pass allvars to the other main functions)?

Comment: like this function initAll(allvars){biopageclass(allvars)//etc.. }

Comment: I think that's a better way to go. One parent function that scopes everything and passes vars along as necessary. Even then it can be helpful/safer to pass the vars directly to the functions that need them rather than relying on closure scoping, but either way will work.

Comment: but with both ways that means the page's js would have to wait for the json to finish being called wouldn't this effectively nullify its asynchronous ability? in essence that would make the function with the json in it the main function so if anything went wrong with the json call the rest of the site's js would not load?

Comment: or does the callback fire regardless of wether or not it could retrive  json?

Comment: hehe just answered my own question